# VBA For Loop for Chart Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, excel-charts

I have the start of some VBA code to format series within a chart. As shown below

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 31").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Patterned msoPatternNarrowHorizontal
End With
```

What I want to do is create a for loop to cycle through all the series with an even tag i.e.

```
FullSeriesCollection(x) Where x is an even number.
```

Until an error is returned because there are no more even series. Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: `For x = 2 to ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count Step 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered in comments... but loop to the `.Count` using `Step 2`:

```
For x = 2 to ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count Step 2
```